# can't install yii2 bower & phpunit

Tags: php, yii2

Please help me.when install yii2

composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.11

```
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (5.7.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/base (2.2.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/verify (0.3.3): Loading from cache
   symfony/console suggests installing symfony/filesystem ()
   symfony/console suggests installing symfony/process ()
   symfony/browser-kit suggests installing symfony/process ()
   symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
  symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/http-kernel ()
  phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.5.1)
  sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
  phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects suggests installing ext-soap (*)
  phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
  phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
  codeception/base suggests installing codeception/specify (BDD-style code blocks)
  codeception/base suggests installing flow/jsonpath (For using JSONPath in REST module)
  codeception/base suggests installing phpseclib/phpseclib (for SFTP option in FTP Module)
  codeception/base suggests installing league/factory-muffin (For DataFactory module)
  codeception/base suggests installing league/factory-muffin-faker (For Faker support in DataFactory module)
  codeception/base suggests installing symfony/phpunit-bridge (For phpunit-bridge support)
  Writing lock file
  Generating autoload files
```

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any question about this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you should install the fxp asset plugin

Just open command prompt and type

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`

And hit enter.after that you can install yii2 advanced

Answer (score 0):

Did you?

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

yii2

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2project
```

but better basic template

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic yii2project
```

codeception localy

```
composer require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```

and globaly

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```

more on www.pceuropa.net/blog/yii2-tests-codeception-configuration-first-test/

Answer (score 0):

Please provide composer.phar version. As of 1.5.0 plugins are always installed ASAP, even before libraries (https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

The 'suggests' lines can be ignored unless you know and are using the requested libraries. If you want those libraries to work, it appears PHP is missing a few extensions. Try getting those installed then re-run  the install composer install command.

When you see
  `Writing lock file
  Generating autoload files`

Composer has been able to execute and complete successfully.